# How do I prove that this value equates to $0$ algebraically?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that, $((\dfrac{1}{1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{-5}+\dfrac{1}{1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{-7}+\cdots)+
(\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{-5}+\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{-7}+\cdots)+(\dfrac{1}{-5}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{-5}\cdot\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{-5}\cdot\dfrac{1}{-7}+\cdots)\cdots)=0--(1)$

This sequence was generated after squaring the sequence:

$\dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}=+1+\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{5}-\dfrac{1}{7}+\dfrac{1}{9}+\dfrac{1}{11}-\cdots--(2)$, and discarding the squares of the terms.

We get,

$\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}=\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\dfrac{1}{5^2}+\cdots+((\dfrac{1}{1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{1}\cdot\dfrac{1}{-5}+\cdots)+
(\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{-5}+\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{-7}+\cdots)+(\dfrac{1}{-5}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1}+\cdots)+\cdots)$

So,
$\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}+(1)$

Basically (1) is the product of every term and the entire sequence except itself. It is easy to see that the value has to equal $0$

But how can I prove this result algebraically, without any reference to trigonometry preferably :)?

Comment: The summation $(2)$ can also be alternatively represented as the the sum of the reciprocals of the roots of the equation $\sec(x)\tan(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, multiplied by a factor of $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$

One could make the argument that, $$\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i\cdot r_j}}=\dfrac{a_2}{a_0}=(1)$$ of the Taylor series of $$\sec(x)\tan(x)-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

This would also result in $0$, since the Taylor series lacks an $x^2$ coefficient, but I want to prove it without any sort of trignometric gymnastics :(

Comment: I doubt that such manipulations are valid , if the sum does not comverge absolutely.

Comment: What is the general term in $(1)$ ?

Comment: There is no general term I believe, just one exception for each term. The terms get multiplied to each other except themselves.

Comment: Upon expanding the (1), we get, $$\dfrac{2}{3}-\dfrac{2}{5}-\dfrac{2}{7}+\dfrac{2}{9}+\dfrac{2}{11}+\cdots-\dfrac{4}{15}-\dfrac{4}{21}+\dfrac{4}{27}+\cdots-\dfrac{5}{45}+\dfrac{5}{63}+\cdots$$

I now think it might be underivable actually ;(